# Keystone v3 on OVH

Tags: openstack-swift, keystone, cyberduck

I am curreny using cyberduck for the storage cloud of ovh.

However, I received an email from OVH to inform me that I have to move from keystone v2.0 to keystone v3 before 24/03/2020.

I have tried a lot of combination but I haven't managed to understand how to fill "project:domain:username". For the other field "Serveur" and "password" I think it could be the same as before (but not sure).

Do someone know how to get the right configuration?

Comment: The support of OVH helped me for this one. in fact "project:domain:username" should be completed with OS_TENANT_NAME:default:OS_USERNAME found in the file openrc.sh which can be downloaded from your user in the project management section.

Answer (score 1):

The support of OVH helped me for this one. in fact "project:domain:username" should be completed with OS_TENANT_NAME:default:OS_USERNAME found in the file openrc.sh which can be downloaded from your user in the project management section